# Parsing doubles from char into a 2D array with sscanf

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array, scanf

Typical for a C beginner, I have some problems understanding arrays, pointers and pointers of arrays. Unfortunately, the info provided here did not help me much, since all deal with "easier" problems. This is my code:

```
/* random.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    double particles[4][22];
    int seed,i,x,y;
    double px_buf, py_buf, pz_buf;

    seed=time(NULL);
    srand(seed);

    /* The random numbers are generated between 1E-12 and 10E-12 */
    /*Double precision floats support up to 15 decimal places*/
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        px_buf=((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*9001E-15;
        py_buf=((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*9001E-15;
        pz_buf=((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*9001E-15;
        particles[0][i]=px_buf;
        particles[1][i]=py_buf;
        particles[2][i]=pz_buf;
        printf("(step: %i) The following noise momentum was generated: (%.15E,%.15E,%.15E)\n",i,px_buf,py_buf,pz_buf);
    }

    sscanf("p[20] = nullvector(45.0000000000106,33.03951484238976,14.97124733712793,26.6317895033428)", \
    "p[20] = nullvector(%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf)",&particles[3][20],&particles[0][20],&particles[1][20],&particles[2][20]);

    for(y=0;y<22;y++){
        for(x=0;x<3;x++){
            printf("%.15E \t", particles[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine, but as you can see, the last four (y=21) array entries are "empty" and I want to fill it in the same manner as its now done with the sscanf line.

I want to replace the sscanf part with a suitable parser function, but I'm utterly confused how to pass pointers correctly, especially how to use the address-of (&) unary operator for sscanf. This is my preliminary parser function:

```
/* parse.c */
void parser(char *input, double **particles){
    sscanf(input, "p[20] = nullvector(%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf)", \
    &particles[3][20],&particles[0][20],&particles[1][20],&particles[2][20]);
    printf("energy: %E, p: (%E, %E, %E)\n",particles[3][20], \
    particles[0][20],particles[1][20],particles[2][20]);
}
```

As you can see, I'm mainly interested in the four doubles preceded by "nullvector(" and I want to take those values out of the string and write them into the 21st "line" of the multiarray 'particles'.

But when I add a

```
#include "parse.c"
(...)
parse("p[20] = nullvector(45.0000000000106,33.03951484238976, \
14.97124733712793,26.6317895033428)",particles);
```

to the main function, it gives me the following errors:

```
[darillian@quantumbox rng]$ gcc random.c -Wall -pedantic -o ../../bin/random 
random.c: In function ‘main’:
random.c:29:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘parse’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from random.c:4:0:
parse.c:1:6: note: expected ‘double **’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[22]’
```

What am I doing wrong? ;D

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is to list such long expressions as `scanf` arguments: `&particles[3][20]`. If you first read into a variable, then copy the variable's value into the array, things might get a lot easier (`scanf` into `x`, then `particles[3][20] = x`).

Comment: `void parser(char *input, double particles[][22])` would be the correct prototype. Two-dimensional arrays have a different memory layout than pointers to pointers. (No time for a proper answer now. If none has been given when I come back, I will.)

Comment: This will be much easier to index if you declare your array as `double[22][4]`, I think...

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks, that works; but seriously - why? I understand that sscanf needs the address-of, but why do I tell parse() that it will recieve an array? I thought one should pass pointers to functions whenever possible...

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec That prototype actually means `void parser(char *input, double (*particles)[22])` that you pass a pointer to an (array of 22 `double`). You need the right type of pointee for the index arithmetic to work correctly, and if you have a `some_type array[rows][columns]`, that is an array of `rows` (array of `columns` `some_type`) and is converted into a pointer to (array of `columns` `some_type`) when passed as a function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you know in advance the size of the vector that represents a particle it makes more sense to inverse your array indexing:

```
#define NUM_PARTICLES 22
/* ... */
double particles[NUM_PARTICLES][4];
```

This then changes your parsing function to be easier to write:

```
void parser(char *input, double particles[][4]){
  sscanf(
    input, 
    "p[20] = nullvector(%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf)", 
    &particles[20][3], &particles[20][0],
    &particles[20][1], &particles[20][2]
  );
}
```

This will compile and do what you want. As an added bonus, the parser does not need to know how many particles are in the field. Instead it only needs to know how the particle is represented (as it should).

The fact that the parser needed to know how many particles were in the field was a big code smell that something was wrong. Changing the program to make more sense nicely takes care of your errors too!

As a tip, think of two dimensional arrays like this:

```
double arr[rows][columns];
```

The [new file](https://gist.github.com/bricef/5247433) will compile without error on Linux with GCC 4.6.

### Clarification

> why do we need to give the number of columns to the parser function?

Because otherwise the function would not have enough information to compute the offset to a given value.

A one dimensional array looks something like this:

```
|value0|value1|value2|...
```

You specify the width of `value` by telling the compiler that this is a `double` array.

So when you access this array, say `arr[17]` the computer actually does this:

```
address of value (bytes) = 17 * width of double (bytes)
```

Now consider a multidimensional array `double arr[17][2]`:

```
|va0|vb0|va1|vb1|va2|vb2|...
```

When you try to access a value, for example `arr[3][1]`, the computer will now perform the following calculation:

```
address of value (bytes) = (3 * width of inner array) + (1 * size of element)
```

where

```
width of inner array = no of elements * size of elements.
```

in our case above, the no of elements of the inner array is 2, and their size is that of a double.

Hence it requires the width of the inner arrays (the 'columns') to find the real address of the value, as otherwise it can't calculate the offsets when indexing.

This is because C uses [row-major ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

Comment: Nice, thanks! Actually, I wanted to have a "table" with four columns and N rows, but I thought that multiarrays hade their indices like a matrix, so (cols)x(rows). Just one thing - why do you omit the row size, but not the col size?

Comment: Because the compiler need to know the number of columns, if you didn't add it in, you'd get an error as the type is incomplete.

Comment: Have added an explanation to answer, hope it makes it a little clearer :)

Comment: Yes, that clarifies things! Thank you :)